# I can't display the videos by Camera roll library, it displays only images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, camera-roll

[I want to show the videos, no need to open them just want to display them in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra6g1.png)

> this is a code i developed to access 15 images from gallery, and now i
>   am trying to access 15 video from the gallery, i saw the documentation
>   and changed the assestType to videos and no changes took place, i am using 
>    expo and the OS is android.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    let controls = props.controls
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      fetchParams: { first: 15 },
      assestType: 'Videos'
    }
    this._storeImages = this._storeImages.bind(this)
    this._logImageError = this._logImageError.bind(this)   }

  componentDidMount() {
    CameraRoll.getPhotos(this.state.fetchParams, this._storeImages, this._logImageError);   }

  _storeImages(data) {
    const assets = data.edges;
    const images = assets.map( asset => asset.node.image );
    this.setState({
        images: images,
    });   }

  _logImageError(err) {
      console.log(err);   }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.imageGrid}>
            { this.state.images.map(image => {
              console.log(image.uri);
              return (
                 <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: image.uri }} />
             );
            })}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );   } }
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this is still waiting to be merged upstream: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16429.

Comment: I don't want to show them on the same component, i want to make component which will display images and another one to display videos, if you know how to display videos from gallery only please send me the documentation or the code. thank you @dikaiosune